# Problema de compatibilidad Select2 y Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, modal, select2

tengo el siguiente problema con bootstrap y select2

lo que sucede es que abro un modal en bootstrap con un formulario de registro y uno de los campos es un selector con buscador de select 2 pero unicamente me deja seleccionar manualmente el campo deseado, no puedo buscar en el dentro del modal de bootstrap, si lo saco del modal funciona con normalidad

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/select2/css/select2.css">
        <script src="librerias/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="librerias/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="modal fade" id="nueva_orden" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nueva Orden de Servicio</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label for="nombre_tecnico">Técnico Encargado</label><br>
                    <select name="nombre_tecnico" id="tecnics">
                        <option value="alonso">Alonso</option>
                        <option value="andres">Andrés</option>
                        <option value="edwin">Edwin</option>
                        <option value="jahdiel">Jahdiel</option>
                        <option value="jose luis">Jose Luis</option>
                        <option value="josue">Josué</option>
                        <option value="kevin">Kevin</option>
                        <option value="lalo">Lalo</option>
                    </select><br>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" Value="Registrar Orden">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tecnics').select2('');
    });
</script>


 ``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso lo puedes resolver definiendo como elemento padre del select2 al elemento que conviertes en modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tecnics').select2({
dropdownParent: 'nueva_orden'
}
);
    });
```